# Swift String format vs Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, string, stringwithformat

I am using swift String(format:...) and need to compute values in the format string itself using ternary operator, something like this but it doesn't compiles.

```
 String(format: "Audio: \(numChannels>1?"Stereo": "Mono")")
```

In Objective-C, I could do like this:

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Audio: %@",  numChannels > 1 ? @"Stereo" : @"Mono"];
```

How do I achieve the same elegance in Swift without having an intermediate variable?

Comment: Note that your Objective-C version does *not* compute the values in the format string itself. The format is *fixed* and the argument computes the string.

Comment: @MartinR That's correct, but in Swift I could compute values, such as '\\(sampleRate/1000)' in format string itself.

Comment: Perhaps you mean string interpolation: `let s = "Audio: \(numChannels > 1 ? "Stereo" : "Mono")"`

Comment: The reason that your Swift code does not compile is the missing spaces around `?` and `:`

Comment: You are right, it was only about spaces :)

Comment: You can even compose the string without `String(format` and without String Interpolation: `"Audio :" + (numChannels > 1 ? "Stereo" : "Mono")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the missing spaces around the operators in the conditional expression, the compiler misinterprets `1?"Stereo"` as optional chaining. It should be

```
String(format: "Audio: \(numChannels>1 ? "Stereo" : "Mono")")
```

instead. However, since the format string has no placeholders at all, this is  equivalent to

```
"Audio: \(numChannels > 1 ? "Stereo" : "Mono")"
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use String(format:) with a placeholder and the conditional expression as the parameter for the placeholder

```
String(format: "Audio = %@", numChannels > 1 ? "Stereo" : "Mono")
```

Comment: It should be `%@` for a Swift string.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that

Comment: I tried %@ and it works, Strange that Swift still has %@ legacy from Objective C.

Comment: @DeepakSharma, the `%@` legacy from Objective-C is because `String(format:)` is not pure Swift but comes by way of the Foundation framework.  Note that you have to import Foundation (or UIKit or AppKit or Cocoa) to use it.  So `"Stereo"` and `"Mono"` get passed as `NSString`.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It works as expected and is one of several valid solutions.

Comment: Code only answers are improved with some explanation